# CPP Code Concerning Classes is Showing Error

Tags: c++, class, prototype

I wrote a pretty simple code for learning the concept of constructors.
I made a Project file in Dev-C++ 5.11, which uses the compiler TDM_GCC 4.9.2 32-bit Release.

Following is the code containing the main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Classy1.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
Classy1 ao(3,4);
ao.printy();
return 0;
}
```

Here is the header file containing the class Classy1:

```
#ifndef CLASSY1_H
#define CLASSY1_H

class Classy1
{
private:
    int v1;
    int v2;
public:
    Classy1(int a,int b);
    void printy();
};

#endif
```

And here is the cpp file containing the constructor and the printy function:

```
#include "Classy1.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Classy1::Classy1(int a,int b)
: v1(a), v2(b)
{
}

Classy1::printy()
{
cout << v1 << " " << v2;
}
```

Now, the compiler is showing an error on compilation:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) again and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The language is called C++, not CPP. You generally don't need to mention the language in the title anyway; that's what tags are for.

Comment: Can we please DO NOT discourage people from learning and asking by downvoting every question around? :).  BTW: Mike Lischke is correct on the issue. Sometimes logs do help, it actually provided the nice hint about candidate method:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a return type for the implementation of `printy()`. It should be:

```
void Classy1::printy()
{
    cout << v1 << " " << v2;
}
```